# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" java

Tags: java, input

I have the error when I save in mysql: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
when I want to register a record in mysql

My **[code](http://subefotos.com/ver/?d1a1943a6005b482a888d23b967caf09o.jpg)**

try 
        {

```
    Proce_Analisis=conn.prepareCall(Insertar_Ana);//
    procedure1=conn.prepareCall(Insertar_Tole);//


    Proce_Analisis.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(a));
    Proce_Analisis.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(eti_lote.getText().trim()));
    Proce_Analisis.setInt(3,Integer.parseInt(eti_num.getText().trim()));
    Proce_Analisis.setInt(4,Integer.parseInt(eti_sem.getText().trim()));
    Proce_Analisis.setString(5,txt_fecha.getText());
    Proce_Analisis.setString(6,eti_rech.getText());
    Proce_Analisis.setString(7,txt_texto.getText());
    Proce_Analisis.setString(8,cmb_ind.getSelectedItem().toString());
    rs=Proce_Analisis.executeQuery();
    rs.first();
```

Comment: Please post your code in the body of your question.

Comment: http://subefotos.com/ver/?d1a1943a6005b482a888d23b967caf09o.jpg

Comment: before parsing your strings to int.. check if the string is null or empty if(str != null && !str.isEmpty())

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're trying to parse a number from an empty strings

I think it's in one of your `Integer.parseInt(str)` calls

Use the debugger when you go over those calls and make sure that the string that you're passing into it is not the empty string: `""`.  If it is, it will throw an exception.

---

once you find out where this is occurring, you have to ask yourself the question:

**Does this string ever have any business being empty**

- If so, than you should check for the empty string before trying to parse your `int`s, and handle the situation accordingly.
- If not, than you should find out why the string is empty in the first place and fix it.

Comment: I solved with comparison  because spent empty a label with a if(!txt_agr_ana.getText().isEmpty()&&!eti_id_var.getText().isEmpty())
thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

before parsing your strings to int.. check if the string is null or empty like this

```
if(str != null && !str.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception and warn the user. 
If it's not a user-end application, just check for empty or null strings beforehand and you shouldn't have this problem.